# Connect to multiple MySQL databases, add to Array if connected, skip if connection is not possible

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a tool for a client that requires connecting to 3 mysql database servers, each on a different location. To do that I create 3 database objects of a database class (db name, username and password are retrieved from a config file) and put them in an array:

```
$db1 = new db('xx.xx.xx.1');
$db2 = new db('xx.xx.xx.2');
$db3 = new db('xx.xx.xx.3');

$dbArray = array($db1, $db2, $db3);
```

This is the part of the class that creates the object:

```
public function __construct($dbHost) {
    /* Get the path to the dbconfig file */
    $this->_configURL = "/path/to/dbconfig/file.ini";

    /* Try and connect to the database if it hasn't been done before */
    if (!isset($this->_mysqli)) {
        /* Load the configuration and put it in an array */
        $dbConfig = parse_ini_file($this->_configURL);            
        $dbUser = $dbConfig["username"];
        $dbPass = $dbConfig["password"];
        $dbName = $dbConfig["dbname"];

        /* Make a new database connection */
        $this->_mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);  
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that the database object is added to an array if a connection is possible. If that's not the case, skip it and try connecting to database 2 and 3. I use the array in the rest of my program.

What is the best way to do this? I tried something with a try catch statement iterating through the IP addresses of the servers. But I couldn't get it to work.

**My solution: Thanks to exussum**

I might not have explained my question correctly, but the code blow does what i need. I have an array with 3 IP-address of the servers and an empty array. The empty array will be filled once creating a database object is succesful. I just needed a little push in the right direction to get this done, it was pretty simple after all...

```
$tmpArray = array('xx.xx.xx.1', 'xx.xx.xx.2', 'xx.xx.xx.3');
$dbArray = array();

foreach ($tmpArray as $k) {
    try {
        //making the connection object
        $dbConfig = new db($k);

        $dbArray[] = $dbConfig;

        continue;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // catch the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the array of object approach that you mentioned?

Comment: Is this: $dbArray = array($db1, $db2, $db3); not working ?

Comment: Adding the 3 objects to an array and using that array later in the program is working fine if all 3 databases can be connected. But if any of them fails, i don;t want them in that array.

Comment: could you not do something like checking if $db object is not null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($dbArray as $k => $dbConfig) {
  try {
    //making the connection object
    continue;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    //you have not been able to connect remove it from the array
    unset($dbArray[$k]);
  }
}
```

assuming your constructor is changed to have

```
$this->_mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);  
/* check connection */
if ($this->_mysqli->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception("Cant connect");
}
```

in there also

UPDATE:

To keep the connected objects

$tmpArray = array('xx.xx.xx.1', 'xx.xx.xx.2', 'xx.xx.xx.3');
$dbArray = array();

```
foreach ($tmpArray as $k) {
    try {
        //making the connection object
        $dbArray[] = new db($k);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // maybe do something to the configs ?
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed break to continue, make sure you make that change also

Comment: thanks for this answer exussum, i don't know if i should accept it as the right answer because it was not, but it was close. I should have explained my question better I think..